# Regexp for scanning substring with tags inside another tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string that may contain substring:

```
<h1 style="margin: 0; padding: 0" class="title_big">Item title <span style="white-space: nowrap"> (5 entries)</span></h1>
```

or just

```
<h1 style="margin: 0; padding: 0" class="title_big">Item title</h1>
```

(with no internal `SPAN`)
Now I can't figure out how to compose regexp. Currently using such one:

```
$pat='/<h1 style="margin: 0; padding: 0" class="title_big">([^>]*)<\/h1>/si';
```

but of course it doesn't return match for substring with internal `SPAN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `$pat` to this instead it should work:

```
$pat = '/<h1 style="margin: 0; padding: 0" class="title_big">(.*?)<\/h1>/uim';
```

Comment: strange, but it works.how can be .*? interpreted? i'm not absolutely familar with regexp (shamy)

Comment: The difference between ".*" and ".*?" is that ".*?" will try to be so short as possible.

Comment: cool. didnt't know, thanx! can it be interpreted like "two quatifiers followed by each other"?